# Spaceships get lost, officers missing

Tags: story-identification, novel

I search for a novel I flipped through, ca. four years ago. There is a space ship officer (lieutenant? captain? navigator?) who accepts to fly a ship for a company. Some time after the start, she (he?) discovers that all officers of the same rank have disappeared on former missions — if I remember correctly, the officers together with their respective space ship.

Comment: As often when I see stuff in Close Vote queue for being "too broad", I'd appreciate it if closevoters could provide 2-3 examples of novel fitting that description. Even if it does look like a common trope, some evidence it's actually too broad would be nice. In the meantime, voted to leave open.

Comment: Try to describe some details - i.e., any visual descriptions you may remember, elements of the story that made it interesting to you, any event at all (even if relatively foggy) that may have happened, etc.  After all, there must have been something beyond "officers of the same rank disappeared" that made this particular story memorable to you.  And those details make it both easier and more fun to search for the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not read the book itself, just the back cover, and flipped through some pages. So I do not remember more. But the book was on a stack with new titles, therefore it must be quite recent.